# yasnippet doesn't work on Windows

Tags: yasnippet

I installed Emacs 25.1.2 on Windows 10 machine, then installed yasnippet library from Elpa. Copied all my snippets from Linux machine. But for some reason none of them work. When I open a file I get this error:

```
File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument integerp nil)
[yas] Loading for `cperl-mode', just-in-time: 
      (lambda nil (yas--load-directory-1 
          (quote D:/me/.emacs.d/yasnippets/cperl-mode) (quote cperl-mode)))!
[yas] Loading compiled snippets from D:/me/.emacs.d/yasnippets/cperl-mode
while: Wrong type argument: integerp, nil
```

Maybe, something is wrong with installed library?

Comment: Can you set `debug-on-error` and post the backtrace?

Comment: @npostavs Will do, when reach that computer

Comment: Before trying to get a backtrace, load the source file (*.el, not *.elc) for the yas code. That might give a more informative backtrace.

Comment: For the record, [a similar report](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/812) could not be reproduced from `emacs -Q`, so this is likely some kind of interaction with another package.

Comment: @npostavs Yes, I had 2 versions of yasnippet installed. I removed the old one. And used the new from Elpa, and it started to work.